# Find $f$ such that it satisfies $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}x=1$ and $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}=C$ for constant $C$

Tags: limits, functions

I need to find a function $f$ such that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}x=1$$ and $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}=C$$ for a constant $C$ that is not zero.
I’ve tried polynomials in $x$ but these seem not to work. I thought maybe using an exponential function might help, but I’m not sure what exactly to use?

Comment: Not such a function at all? Or just not such an exponential function?

Comment: Of course there is such a function (assuming that $x\to 0$ is not a typo in your second limit), just take $f(x)=x^2$ for $x<1$ and $f(x)=x$ for $x\geq1$.

Comment: You can even insist that such a function be infinitely differentiable, and can get an example, although construction will be a little more involved. Essentially, you are asking for a function, while specifying its behaviour near $0$ and for large enough values of the variable. It can do what it wants in the middle, and plenty of regularity can be imposed.

Comment: Give it a bit more thought, maybe along the lines of $Ax^p / (1 + Bx^q)$.

Comment: Following your comment, I’m trying to come up with a solution x^p/(1+x^q) however I’m struggling to find a solution that works for both limits. Any suggestions for p or q?

Comment: @Hannah: Again, give it some thought. Near $x=0$ you want the function to look like $Cx^2$, so that suggests $A = C$ and $p = 2$. Now to deal with the limit at $\infty$ you want the function to look like $x$ which suggests $q = 1$ and $A/B = 1$. The ability to understand asymptotics and to construct examples like this might prove very helpful in your further studies. Starting with polynomials and exponentials as you did is good; you'll want to add rational functions to your toolkit!

Answer (score 0):

The rational functions
$$f_n(x)=\frac{x^{n+1}+Cx^2}{x^n+1}\quad(n\ge 2)$$
are solutions.

Answer (score 0):

What about
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x &\text{ if }|x|\geq 1 \\
Cx^2 &\text{ if }|x| < 1
\end{cases}\quad ?$$